# Show progress bar when sending pages to the printer (WPF)

Tags: wpf, printing, flowdocument

I am creating printouts in WPF using flow documents. These printouts are set in separate window where DocumentViewer is placed. 
When user clicks print I would like to show a progress bar that informs about current page that is sending to the printer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly where your print code is, or where you want the progress bar, but I did something similar to this recently. This will be in VB.net.

First of all, create a new progressbar in the same class as the code you use to send the page to the printer. Then, we're going to take advantage of the "top-down" order in a block of code to change the progress bar.

The progress bar's value should be set to "0" be default. Now, in the code for sending the page to the printer, you're going to increase the progressbar's value (such as with the code "MyProgressBar.Value = MyProgressBar.Value + 1"). Put this code in between each line of the code you want to show progress for.

I would change the "+ 1" part of the code, however, to another value, so your progress bar progresses equally after each step. If you have three lines of code, then use "+ 33" (100\3), four lines use "+ 25", etc.

Finally, at the end of the code, set "MyProgressBar.Value = 100"

This only works, however, if you have access to a code longer than one line. For one line of code, I'm not sure how this works, unless you can get to the block of code that line points to.

If you have to use code from another class, you may need to do something like...

```
Dim MyWindowWhereProgressIs As New MyWindowWhereProgressIs
```

And then, each time you need to change the value, try...

```
MyWindowWhereProgressIs.MyProgressBar.Value = MyWindowWhereProgressIs.MyProgressBar.Value + 1
```

I'm not entirely sure whether or not those last two lines of code will work, as I'm away from Visual Studio right now, but it is worth a shot.